# Why I am getting a syntax error when everything is legal accepting a csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am getting a syntax error while reading a csv file . I know this might silly to most of you . But it is of utmost importance to me right now . Actually , i got a Unicode error before which i overcame my prefixing with 'r' . Now , it is showing a syntactical error .

```
 train = pd.read_csv(r 'C:\Users\Siddhu\Downloads\train-images-idx3-ubyte.csv')
 test = pd.read_csv(r 'C:\Users\Siddhu\Downloads\t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.csv')



File "<ipython-input-23-2341446e2439>", line 1
train = pd.read_csv(r 'C:\Users\Siddhu\Downloads\train-images-idx3-ubyte.csv')
                                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `r '123'` != `r'123'` (note the space between `r` and the string)

Comment: Technically, you are getting the syntax error before your code even runs, not while reading a CSV file. You haven't really fixed the Unicode error yet, you've just introduced a new error that is found *before* the Unicode error.

Answer (score 3):

The space between the r and the file path:

```
  train = pd.read_csv(r 'C:\Users\Siddhu\Downloads\train-images-idx3-ubyte.csv')
                       ^
```

to

```
  train = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Siddhu\Downloads\train-images-idx3-ubyte.csv')
```

It should work if you remove the space!